# Make specific color in a texture transparent

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, shaders

I am working with very old model files that have BMP textures. The designers did not use a transparency in the textures or a separate alpha b/w texture. They used a specific color value that was then removed by the engine to create a transparency, similar to a chroma key. In this case, all textures used a bright purple/pink color.

I cannot modifying the original texture images by converting them to PNG and add an alpha. I would like to figure out how to do it all in nodes.

The goal is to have this value keyed out and transparent. I have been messing around in the shader editor and cannot figure this out.  I've also been looking around online and in this forum, but the only search terms I can think of are chroma-keying which only results in Compositing results, which I don't believe is what I'm looking for.

Here is an example of the texture (its very small) and it's context:

[image: chain texture]

[image: chain in context]

Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: This may not be possible in Blender. Use external dedicated software.

Comment: looks like its very much possible @Lukasz-40sth! phew!

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth Name calling and personal attacks will not be tolerated here. Your previous post had already been removed, mind your attitude

Comment: **I** should mind it? **I** was attacked with this "phew" and it's him whose comment should be deleted.

Comment: It's possible there's a language barrier happening.  "phew" in the US is an expression of relief after being concerned.  You said it may not be possible to do this. I received a bunch of good answers that all worked. I was expressing: "I'm so relieved I could do this inside Blender like I had hoped. What a relief! (phew)" Hopefully that's clear!  Here's an example of "phew" in practice by an American president: https://gph.is/2pbOBPQ

Comment: I didn't know that. So we have another difference between UK and US. Quite significant one as most dictionaries say it means disgust, similar to Polish __Fuj!__ pron. Fooy

Comment: i didn't know that. glad we sorted that out!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a "Mix RGB" node set to "Subtract" and invert the resulting mask to get your alpha value.

[image]

Note : "Compare" node is a "Math" node with the operation set to "Compare"

Note : "Length" node is a "Vector Math" node with the operation set to "Length". [Why it is important.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194471/86891)

Result :

[image]

You can tweak the third input of the compare node if your magenta isnt pure, to add a threshold. This will also progressively get rid of colors that are closer to the input color. Example :

[image]

Also real-life example (Green screen) :

[image]

Comment: Oh man, this is amazing :). It works just like color range command in Photoshop. Already saved it as a node group. https://imgur.com/vkKX4Na

Comment: @JachymMichal Nice ! Do you plan on plugging something in your color ramp when using this ?

Comment: Not really, I just used it as a slider. Anyways, nice Sméagol :).

Comment: love this answer.  honestly, i love all these answers. seeing the same thing achieved different ways is such a terrific way to learn.  I used your approach, but i also changed my texture's interpolation to CLOSEST instead of the default linear. it kept the hard edges on the key

Answer (score 6):

You could simply push the contrast of your image with a *ColorRamp* and use this as a mask between the original and a *Transparent* node. As suggested by Jachym Michal, when using *Principled BSDF*, just plug the *ColorRamp* into the *Alpha* input.

[image]

Comment: Great answer :). Also, when using *Principled BSDF*, just add a colorramp https://imgur.com/l4JhuKn

Comment: Use cycles, does not work in eevee.

Comment: @node in Eevee you need to go in the Materials panel > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend instead of Opaque, is it your problem?

Comment: got it to work in eevee too,, blend mode / alpha clip .

Answer (score 6):

Based entirely on Gorgious' answer, I've put together an easy-to-use nodegroup.
It's similar to Color Range selection in Photoshop.

1. Pick a color to select
2. Adjust the color Range
3. Invert the colors if needed

It outputs a black-and-white mask, useful as alpha or fac input.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No problem, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 5):

Pure purple should be RGB(1,0,1) so you can make a mask with Math node, Greater Than operation. Red value should be greater than some threshold value *and* blue value should be greater than some threshold as well so they should be multiplied:

[image]

[image]

In this particular case you probably do not want to use anti-aliasing since it will not work well with this technique, so maybe set interpolation of the texture to "Closest". The sample texture could work anyway, but if you have more colourful textures, keying the purple might become an issue with other types of interpolation.

Answer (score 5):

@Gorgious 's answer, because of the [implicit conversion of color > scalar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32242/35559), compares the [luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) of the colors (using the higher tree below). It selects the colors in the middle, highlighted  B/W band in the illustration, when compared to the mid-green:

[image]

Although, as he shows, this works perfectly adequately, for accuracy, you may want to compare the 3D *distance* between the colors in RGB space by introducing a vector math *Length* node, (as in the lower tree,) which selects the colors in the bottom B/W band.

Comment: This is awesome ! All the answers could benefit from it. The "correctness' of the spectrum mask brought by the length node is indeed invaluable when dealing with compressed images and random colors shifts start popping everywhere. Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: @Gorgious Phew! I thought I might be being undiplomatic .. To be fair to you, there are places where, despite having a wider/more scattered spectrum, Luminance might be a better discriminator.

Comment: Don't sweat it :) I think only dummies get angry when someone corrects them, especially on the context of this site... Have a nice day

Answer (score 4):

You can have anti-aliasing and transparency and use only nodes, but that won't be a small node tree.

[image: test render][image]

1. Original image, linear interpolation
2. closest interpolation, background removed similar way as other answers [image: nodes]
3. linear interpolation, otherwise same node network as 2.
4. monster node network emulating linear interpolation, screenshot would be unusable, check linked blend file

My recommendations, in order:

- reevaluate if you really need to not convert source files,
- use closest interpolation,
- check if you maybe could somehow do the conversions in python in blender in a way that meets your constraints,
- or emulate interpolation mode you want using monster node network

also, the advantage of emulation is you could use weird interpolation mode that blender does not have normal way