# How to change transparency color in material options? 2.8+

Tags: rendering, materials, transparency

I have two images. One on black background and the other on white.
How to pick a color to act like transparency mask? How to separate it and put in alpha?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176419/make-specific-color-in-a-texture-transparent/176425#176425

Comment: @moonboots adding ColorRamp helped to remove white color. Thank you. Can you post it plz so I can pick thats as a solution?

Comment: I think the topic is going to be closed as it has already been answered  ;)