# How would I make the unpainted part of a texture paint image not affect object color when mixing?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, image, texture-painting

I am trying to model a face in Blender.

I am having an issue where I am trying to use texture paint to make the lips red. I have already set up a procedural skin texture for the head, which works perfectly except it also makes the lips skin-colored.

In order to fix this problem, I tried to texture paint on a red color. Unfortunately, when I created the image for the texture paint, everything was black. This made it impossible for me to combine the procedural skin texture and the texture paint image into the base color of the face without severely darkening the rest of the head.

See if this image helps:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a math node set to "Less than" with a very low threshold, and use that in the factor input of the mix RGB.

Illustration :

[image]

Comment: How do you determine the value?

Comment: The value of a color is the highest of each of its three color components : Red, Green, Blue. So it depends on the mask color, but since the answer mentions a black color, its value should be 0, or around 0 if it is not pure black. If you want more information, you can take a look at my other answer on the subject : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/176427/86891

Comment: Great solution! This worked perfectly. However, one thing that I would like to point out is that texture painting often requires the "less than" comparison value to a much larger number, like 0.3 as the texture paint brush leaves a gradient streak rather than a solid one.

Comment: @EricXue True ! You can use the math node set to "Compare" instead of "Less than" to tweak the threshold (more info in the link I provided higher up)