# Editing some textures

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, edit-mode

I have these two textures and I want that the red colored emissions will get left all other things get fully black that is everything except the red color in the images get left and others get fully black.[image]

[image].
.

I want to convert these textures like this
[image]
To this
[image]

Comment: Your texture contains also baked emission lights, on other hand -reference texture is only source of light. Do you want to separate only source or all red baked in texture. For me it is hard to say what are only sources of light.

Comment: Also ... Do you want to separate from texture or this is your model that you baked? Because if you have model before bake you can bake only Emission pass.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make specific color in a texture transparent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176419/make-specific-color-in-a-texture-transparent)

Comment: @JachymMichal When I tried Gorgious (and yours) node tree it started to select white pixels before it handled whole range of red pixels (the same is visible on Sméagol image on greenscreen - it takes white skin pixels before green pixels on edge. Even with Robin's pointing to Lenght node and Luminance it still takes a lot of bright grey even a lot of dark red is there https://imgur.com/0k8mGQJ

Comment: You're right, looks like having a more robust solution would be nice :). I've got some bounty points lying around, if you're interested... :D

Answer (score 2):

*You can try ... directly Shader editor ... or Compositor that has more advanced Matte nodes and save Mask texture ... or any other image editor (application) that can select a color range.*

---

**Shader**

Since you need red color ... I separated RGB channel and used G and B channel to Difference from R channel.

[image]

Since red color is contaminated by other colors (is blending to "metal" part of texture), you cant expect miracle ... but it can work kind of ...

[image]
[image]

Green color for emission is used just to see how well matte (mask) served for separation.

Comment: Thanks for this great idea I don't know it ,but I want to know that how to remove everything except the red emissions with nodes or anything else.

Comment: Check the output socket of RGB Curve node that is a mask for red color https://imgur.com/0SqERHw