# How can improve my removal of a green screen on a MATERIAL only, not compositing?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have imported a video into Blender utilising the Image to Plane addon. With this, I needed to remove a greenscreen that is apart of the video. I couldn't use any compositing tools, because it's obviously a material. I used one method to remove the greenscreen, but it comes out with green artifacts in places where it really shouldn't be, specifically the outer edge and around the subject its self. I was wondering how could I make this better? Is it even possible to make it better than this?

[image: Example of the artifacts]

[image: The full pipeline]

[image: The nodes]

I've fiddled around with the numbers, but at some point it sacrifices the transparency of the subject, and that's also not great.

[image: See through]

I know how to do a pretty good greenscreen in the compositing tab, but that doesn't seem to be truly helpful in this case.

It's important to note that I'm quite a novice when it comes to this, and this effect needs to be reprouducable on a mass scale as well.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make specific color in a texture transparent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176419/make-specific-color-in-a-texture-transparent)

Comment: Specifically this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194471/86891 which should give the most accurate result

Comment: @Gorgious It seems like it should be perfect but it doesn't really seem to work :s I must be doing something wrong