# Help needed with changing the colors in a video

Tags: node-editor, edit-mode, video

I am trying to get the colors in the video to be changeable. I need something that could completely change any one color in a video, specifically black to white, but I don't want to invert it to make all white objects black. I can work without changing the other colors, but it would be nice if I could do them too.
I am not very experienced with Blender, so there may be a very obvious answer here that I am just not seeing. One thing I tried was turning the black into a green screen with the keying node, but that messes with the other colors. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: aaah, if things were so simple :) when ppl use green screens, they avoid having anything green on screen, to not mess up their keying. Every colour has some black mixed in, in its shadows, which is why we don't use black screens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mask and convert color in photo/video](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191265/mask-and-convert-color-in-photo-video) and [selective color correction](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97335/selective-color-correction/97345#97345)

Comment: and  [color keying using the vse](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78947/how-can-i-do-color-keying-using-the-vse/78972#78972)